# Is it sensible to pass WAMS database calls through to a full SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Is the full functionality of SQL Database such as federation, new replication features, etc available with the SQL database that's backing WAMS?  If not I'm considering using server-side scripts to simply pass WAMS database calls through to a full version of SQL Database.

Assuming this is possible with node's mssql object, is it sensible to do such a thing?  WAMS is a brilliant entry point to the datastores, but I'm concerned I'll end up deprived of advanced database functionality if I dump all the data straight into the WAMS database.

**EDIT:**
More specifically, are features such as Federation, Active Geo Replication, and Self Service Restore [discussed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/04/sql-database-updates-coming-soon-to-the-premium-preview.aspx) available when using WAMS?  If not can WAMS users gain access to these features by passing calls to the WAMS endpoints through to a separate SQL Premium database?

Mark

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special with an Azure Mobile Services referenced Azure SQL Database, it's just like any other Azure SQL Database. You can even use it outside of Azure Mobile Services

Comment: To be clear then you're saying that when I decide to scale out and federate the WAMS database across continents I do that without breaking WAMS?

Comment: afaik, you can't setup federation members to be in different data centres, if that's what you mean by 'across continents'. Likewise, you may want to check the latest guidance on scaling out Azure SQL, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn495641.aspx

Comment: Thanks JuneT, but the question isn't about SQL Database scaleout so much as understanding what if any of the underlying SQL functionality is off the table because of WAMS.  Consider this new functionality in SQL Premium: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/04/sql-database-updates-coming-soon-to-the-premium-preview.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/04/sql-database-updates-coming-soon-to-the-premium-preview.aspx)   How much of this can we expect to have access to without breaking WAMS?  I'm editing the question to be more specific in this regard

Comment: afaik, there is nothing there that should break WAMS. and most of these new features are not necessarily features you access from an SDK, they are at the database level (e.g., Self Service Restore is not necessarily something you want to invoke from the WAMS SDK). from SQL Azure perspective, WAMS is just like any other client application accessing SQL Azure. If you want to use Federations, the EF support on the .NET backend can easily provide that. If you want to configure Geo-Replication, that's happens at the database level. you can replicate a WAMS SQL Database.

Comment: What you're saying certainly sounds plausible.  My suspicions come from the fact that until recently WAMS would not allow anything but an integer primary key.  Now we can use a string for PK which is good but still raises the question that WAMS may have some expectations about the underlying database that prevent what we can do on the db level.